# Cython, cannot access class member in magic arithmetic functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

Consider the following test class:

```
cdef class Test:
cdef int a

def __cinit__(self, a):
    self.a = a

def __add__(self, other):
    return Test(self.a + other.a)
```

Compiling this and executing

```
import test    
t = test.Test(1)
t2 = test.Test(2)

t3 = t + t2
```

yields the following error

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    t3 = t + t2
  File "test.pyx", line 285, in test.Test.__add__
    return Test(self.a + other.a)
AttributeError: 'test.Test' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Why is that the case? Implementing other magic functions, like **copy**, in a similar fashion has worked out fine so far..

Comment: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/special_methods.html#arithmetic-methods - you're likely using Cython 0.29.x (which is described as the "old" behaviour in the documentation)

Comment: But isn't this just about ´__radd__` ? So I should still be able to use ´__add__` if I implement type-checking of the self and other argument

Comment: It should be `def __add__(Test self, Test other)`, otherwise you cannot access `cdef a`. It is obvious that `other` must be explicitly typed. It might be a bug, that `self` must be explicitly typed as well - normally Cython does this automatically for `self`.

Comment: `self` must be deliberately typed here because `1+Test()` calls `Test.__add__(1, Test())` (in the days before `__radd__`)

Comment: But what if I also want to allow say `1 + Test()` ? Normally I would check the type within `__add__`, but now its arguments are already typed..

Comment: You'd define `def __add__(self, other)` (i.e. untyped), then do `isinstance(self, Test)`, `isinstance(other, Test)` and cast before accessing `a` so that Cython can access the C attributes (e.g. `(<Test>other).a` or `cdef Test otherAsTest = other`). Return `NotImplemented` for cases you can't handle

Comment: Yes that did the job! Thanks!